# Using Instal Shield how can one install an applcaition(file transfer,prerequiste) through custom dialog checkbox

Tags: installation, installshield

I am trying to install three application by creating custom dialog .Within Custom dialog there are checkbox and Onclicking checkbox and thereafter doing next I want my application to  do file transfer ,install the prerequiste based on which checkbox is checked .I want this to happen  for all the three application.Please suggest how to do it and how can we give the condition to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a custom dialog for a Basic MSI, I would suggest the following:

1. Ensure each application in question is part of a separate feature. If you go with the original dialog set, this would potentially let the user select them by feature name, or you could hide them. These features should have meaningful names, along the lines of `App1`, `App2`, `App3`.
2. Ensure your three check boxes are associated with different properties, such as `INSTALL_APP_1`, `INSTALL_APP_2`, `INSTALL_APP_3`. I show public properties here out of habit, but since they will be used in the same sequence (on the same dialog box, even), it's okay to use private properties. And use suffixes more meaningful than 1, 2, 3.
3. Adding multiple [control events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368036) to the Next or Install button on the dialog box you described. For each feature you want to control this way:

   - Add an [AddLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367537) control event, with an argument of the feature name (e.g. App1), conditioned to execute when the check box is checked (i.e. with a condition like `INSTALL_APP_1`
   - Add a [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371210) control event, with an argument of the feature name (e.g. App1), conditioned to execute when the check box is not checked (i.e. with a condition like `NOT INSTALL_APP_1`.

4. If you are going to show this dialog box during maintenance, you should also initialize the values of the check box properties (`INSTALL_APP_1`, etc.) so that merely going past this dialog box doesn't change their installation state. You can use [feature-state condition syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012#feature_and_component_state_values) (`!App1`, etc.) to do so in SetProperty custom actions scheduled just before showing the maintenance dialog (e.g. set property `INSTALL_APP_1` to the value `1` with condition `!App1=3`).
5. If these features are shown in a feature selection control, be sure to update the properties accordingly. Do so on the Next button of that dialog using a combination of the feature state and feature action syntaxes. The property should be `1` if the feature is currently installed and not being removed, or is being installed; it should be set to empty (`{}`) otherwise.

This is a lot of steps, but together they help ensure the features will act as a user expects. If he does nothing to change their state, they should persist as previously set. If visible in both the feature selection control and via check boxes, they should act in sync.

As far as prerequisites, if you mean the InstallShield concept of prerequisites, this you can [associate prerequisites with the features](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/AssociatingPrereqsFeatures.htm) for those apps. If you just mean other components inside your MSI, those work perfectly well with the features defined in step 1 as well.